# How to change mat-select placeholder color?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material-5

I am trying to change the color of a mat-select placeholder. It works fine if this is 'background-color' but not if this is 'color'. Here is my css code:

```
/deep/ .mat-select-placeholder {
  color: red;
 }

 .mat-select-placeholder {
   color: red;
 }
```

Here is the hmtl code:

```
<mat-form-field class="formfield-size-medium">
  <mat-select [formControlName]="formControl.nationality" name="Nationality"
          placeholder="Nationalities" 
      class="class-mat-select" multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let nationality of 
             nationalityList.nationalities" [value]="nationality.value">
              {{getNationalityValue(nationality.value)}}
          </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried also with /deep/ but it still does not work. The text is always in black. So why it works with background-color and not with color? 
My other issue is that when there is a mat-option selected in the list, the placeholder (looking smaller) is always in black even when color is set to red and background-color is also set to red. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I have manage to change the color of placeholder like this

*style.css*

```
mat-form-field span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:orange !important;
}

mat-form-field.mat-focused span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:green !important;
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53435524)

Comment: Thanks. It works well with matInput. With mat-select it works if focused, but not if not focused.

Comment: can you check the demo @corleone88

Comment: Your example works very well, but I think that it does not work for me maybe because I work with Angular 5. Unfortunately, because of complicated project management, I cannot upgrade to Angular 6 or 7. So maybe there is a bug with Angular-Material 5.

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-angular-material-with-angular-v5-kc8ofj

Comment: Hi, thanks again @malbarmawi for your test app in Angular 5. I downloaded the project on my PC, installed the dependencies but I cannot get the same thing as with stackblitz.com. No colour and the labels are under the input and the list element. It is like it does not care about the css.

Comment: After I added an ::ng-deep prefix this worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-placeholder {
    color: orange !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extremely similar to @malbarmavi's answer, I just needed to add ::ng-deep to get this to work:

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:orange !important;
}

::ng-deep mat-form-field.mat-focused span.mat-form-field-label-wrapper label {
  color:green !important;
}
```